# Linear space with basic vectors of outer space

Tags: group-theory

In general, we set a n-dimensional linear space $\mathscr{L}$, then we would have n-dimensional basic vectors. Let's look at this in different way. We find the basic vectors from the outer space which contains $\mathscr{L}$. How we do it? Can we obtain less basic vectors? If I set a infinite space which contains $\mathscr{L}$, it needs infinite basic vectors to describe the little $\mathscr{L}$ space. Everyone will say that this method is nonsense, it is really ture? I always think that everything has its good side.

Comment: Define "outer space" please.

Comment: An $n$-dimensional linear space is *defined* by the very fact, that you need $n$ basis vectors to span it. So even if a linear space $V$ is embedded as subspace in some space $W$ of higher dimension, you can still choose $n$ vectors from $W$ (not necessarily from the basis of $W$ you use) which span all of $V$.

Comment: In my sense, outer space is complementary subspace for $\mathscr{L}$. It is impossible to find the basic vectors from outer space to span all of $\mathscr{L}$. Maybe we can define the basic vectors of $\mathscr{L}$ with outer space and other necessary information? Or it is just a joke?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little unclear what you are asking, but I will give it a shot.

Space-time from relativity is an example of a 4 dimensional space where 3 of the dimensions come from outer space. You can pick any basis for outer space. Usually you pick ordinary mutually perpendicular unit vectors. You pick a unit vector in the time-like direction for the 4th basis vector. Any vector in space-time has 4 coordinates (x,y,z,t).

You can arrange the coordinates differently, (t,x,y,z). But the number is always the same. Every n-dimensional vector space has n basis vectors and n coordinates.

Infinite dimensional spaces are a little tricky. A typical space contains only vectors with a finite length. You need an infinite number of basis vectors and an infinite number of coordinates to describe an infinite dimensional space. Given the usual metric, (1,1,1,1,...) is not a vector in that space. It would have an infinite length. (1, 1/2, 1/4, ...) is a vector.

If you embed a 3 dimensional space in an infinite dimensional space, 3 of the coordinates are for the embedded space. I don't know of any physics reason to do this. Infinite dimensional spaces that physicists use have other uses, such as Fourier Analysis. These do not have outer space embedded in them.

Comment: Thank you for details on the infinite spaces. More clearer discussion is added on the comments.